# Issue with ARM TTK Tool

Tags: azure, azure-devops, azure-pipelines, azure-resource-manager

[image]I am trying to run the test for ARM template  using the ARM TTK toolkit.
I am using YAML pipeline as code.
I was following this link https://azurehangout.com/infrastructure-as-code-security-for-azure-part-2-arm-template-test-toolkit-arm-ttk/

But somehow my pipeline fails at the task : Run deploymentTemplate tests from ARM Template Tester Toolkit

Please see the output of the task and i don't see the Publish Artifacts stage with a green check mark

```
  [+] DependsOn Best Practices (74 ms)
    [+] Deployment Resources Must Not Be Debug (27 ms)
    [+] DeploymentTemplate Must Not Contain Hardcoded Uri (23 ms)
    [+] DeploymentTemplate Schema Is Correct (9 ms)
    [+] Dynamic Variable References Should Not Use Concat (10 ms)
D:\a\1\s\arm-template-toolkit\arm-ttk\testcases\deploymentTemplate\IDs-Should-Be-Derived-From-ResourceIDs.test.ps1 : Property: "id" must use one of the following expressions for an resourceId property:
            extensionResourceId,resourceId,subscriptionResourceId,tenantResourceId,if,parameters,reference,variables,subscription,guid
At D:\a\1\s\arm-template-toolkit\arm-ttk\Test-AzTemplate.ps1:246 char:21
+                     . $myModule $TheTest @testInput 2>&1 3>&1
+                     ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
+ CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (@{id=[variables('su…NetworkRules[0].id}:PSObject) [Write-Error], WriteErrorException
+ FullyQualifiedErrorId : ResourceId.Should.Contain.Proper.Expression,IDs-Should-Be-Derived-From-ResourceIDs.test.ps1
##[debug]Exit code: 1
##[debug]Leaving Invoke-VstsTool.
##[error]PowerShell exited with code '1'.
##[debug]Processed: ##vso[task.logissue type=error]PowerShell exited with code '1'.
##[debug]Processed: ##vso[task.complete result=Failed]Error detected
##[debug]Leaving D:\a\_tasks\PowerShell_e213ff0f-5d5c-4791-802d-52ea3e7be1f1\2.186.0\powershell.ps1.
Finishing: Run deploymentTemplate tests from ARM Template Tester Toolkit
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure about the task you're using to run it, but you want to make sure you continue on error - otherwise the first failure you have from the TTK will be the last because the task will stop.

This is what we use for our settings (we use json):

https://github.com/Azure/azure-quickstart-templates/blob/master/test/pipeline/pipeline.import.azure.master.json#L838-L863

And just running that in a generic PowerShell core task.

Comment: - task: PowerShell@2
  displayName: 'Run deploymentTemplate tests from ARM Template Tester Toolkit'
  continueOnError: true
  inputs:
    targetType: 'inline'
    script: |
      cd D:\a\1\s\arm-template-toolkit\arm-ttk
      Import-Module ./arm-ttk.psd1
      get-childitem $(Build.SourcesDirectory)/IAAS/ARM/*.json | Test-AzTemplate  -test "Resources Should Have Location","Location Should Not Be Hardcoded", "VM Size Should Be A Parameter","Variables Must Be Referenced"
    pwsh: true
    workingDirectory: '$(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)/arm-template-toolkit/arm-ttk'

Comment: My last task is publish results task but it doesn't show anything in artifacts after the job finishes

Comment: - task: PublishBuildArtifacts@1
  displayName: 'Publish Artifacts'
  inputs:
    PathtoPublish: $(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)
    ArtifactName: TstResults

Comment: Get this message in the job results #[warning]Directory 'D:\a\1\a' is empty. Nothing will be added to build artifact 'TstResults'.

Comment: Why  is it  not displaying the results in the artifacts any idea?

Comment: I'm not familiar with the "Publish Artifacts" task - though by default TTK won't create a results file, so it may very well be the case that the folder is empty.